# Can not start redis in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, redis

I am using laradock to run the project,
First time It's ok when I start redis with docker. But when I start with another project.
It's not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puKgf.png)

My Dockerfile

```
FROM redis:5.0-alpine

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

## For security settings uncomment, make the dir, copy conf, and also start with the conf, to use it
#RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/redis
#COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

VOLUME /data

EXPOSE 6379

#CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

When I build redis

```
Building redis
Sending build context to Docker daemon  65.02kB
Step 1/5 : FROM redis:5.0-alpine
 ---> ff5f1979586f
Step 2/5 : LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a42019d45de4
Step 3/5 : VOLUME /data
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54611bec2839
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 6379
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4c32f18d5cbf
Step 5/5 : CMD ["redis-server"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed80478aed7f
Successfully built ed80478aed7f
Successfully tagged laradock_redis:latest
Starting laradock_redis_1 ... done
Attaching to laradock_redis_1
redis_1                | 
redis_1                | *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
redis_1                | Reading the configuration file, at line 2
redis_1                | >>> 'requirepass'
redis_1                | Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
laradock_redis_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Try newer [redis:alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis)

Comment: compose logs show container for redis is not being recreated, just getting started, try with removing the container using docker rm or docker-compose down. Then restart and check the container is being created.

Comment: I also try connect redis local to docker workspace but It also has problem : Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Answer (score 0):

I just remove laradock,
remember stop docker composer before it

```
sudo docker-compose down
```

after that, Please re-install laradock

```
git submodule add --fource https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git
```

after that restart services you want to start

```
sudo docker-compose up -d nginx mysql redis workspace
```

```
laradock_redis_1              docker-entrypoint.sh --req ...   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp,:::6379->6379/tcp
```

All services in up status